# Windows 7: Can't see ISO file in C:\

Tags: windows-7

I used DVD shrink to create an ISO file and saved it into C:\

The ISO file is visible with some programs but not with others.

The file is not hidden as far as I am aware.

But it cannot be seen by Windows Explorer, DVD Decrypter or a bunch of other programs.

If I search for the file using Windows 7's Start Menu search tool, I can see the file and I can right click and select Properties. The Properties window appears OK, but if I try to change tabs on the property window, I receive an error message as though the file is not there.

DVD Shrink can still open the file OK. I can also find the file using Agent Ransack (a file searching tool), but then I cannot open it.

What gives?

Comment: That's quite odd. What file attributes does it have? Open a command prompt and type `attrib C:\filename.iso` -- what does it say?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check to see if it's in in `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore`. In Windows 7 you don't typically have permission to write to the root folder unless explicitly running as an administrator, so the access gets redirected. Unfortunately, this isn't always reflected when trying to subsequently view the file.